# Number SQL rows based on query sorting?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Say I have a set of SQLite rows that have an auto increment field "_id", a string field "title", an integer field "type", and an integer field "number".

There are only a few types (i.e. 1, 2, 3).
All the number fields are currently blank, and I need to fill them with the numbers 1 through N for all rows of type 1.  These numbers should be in the same sorting order as the title field (Ascending).

After the rows have been numbered, `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE type=1 ORDER BY title` should return the exact same result as `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE type=1 ORDER BY number`.

I could do this by querying `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE type=1 ORDER BY title` and looping through all the _id's to update the numbers row by row, but I'm looking for a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the id to the number of rows with a smaller title:

```
UPDATE  YourTable
SET     Id = (
             select  count(*)
             from    YourTable t2
             where   t2.title < YourTable.title
             ) + 1
```

This assumes that there are no two rows with the same title.

Comment: Would be great if I could make that assumption

Answer (score 0):

If you define a temporary table with an auto increment field, then copying your records there in title order should assign them numbers in the right order - then you can copy the new numbers back to the original table. I don't have SqlLite to check the code exactly, but here's how it works in Sql Server, using a table variable to keep it simple:

```
DECLARE @autonumbering TABLE (_id INT, title NVARCHAR(100), number INT identity);

INSERT INTO @autonumbering (_id, title) 
 SELECT _id, title FROM realtable WHERE type = 1 ORDER BY title;

UPDATE realtable
 SET realtable.number = autonumbers.number
  FROM realtable JOIN @autonumbering AS autonumbers 
   ON realtable.type = 1 AND realtable._id = autonumbers._id;
```